# Why when running hundreds of VBS files at once, only about 50 or so succeed each time

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I've got a list of about 600 products where I need to get inventory data.
I can get this per product from an internal site, where I copy a table that shows specifically where the products are stored (warehouse, location).
Since VBA webscraping would do this in serial it takes around 10~15 minutes to get all 600.

I can make this time a lot shorter by doing it parallel via VBScript.
My VBA code dynamically creates the VBScript below that pulls the data and puts it back into the Excel sheet.
It works, but only for 50~60 products at a time, no matter how many VBScript files I launch. The rest fails and doesn't return output or doesn't put it into the sheet.
Does anyone know any reason why this might happen?

Is there something I can do to adjust my vbscript code so more will succeed?
Thanks for any help!

VBSCRIPT:

```
Dim oXML, oXL, product, sHTML, tabl, x, y
On Error Resume Next

Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set oXML = Wscript.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

oXML.Open "GET", "internal-site", False
oXML.SetAutoLogonPolicy AutoLogonPolicy_Always
oXML.send

sHTML = oXML.responseText

x = InStr(sHTML, "<table  cellpadding=1  border=0 cellspacing=0 align=center>")
y = InStr(sHTML, "</table><br>") + 8
tabl = Mid(sHTML, x, y - x)

RandomNumber = Int(Rnd * 500)
Wscript.Sleep RandomNumber
oXL.workbooks("a3.xlsb").sheets("A").Cells(8, 3) = Mid(tabl, 1, 32767)
oXL.workbooks("a3.xlsb").sheets("A").Cells(8, 4) = Mid(tabl, 32768, 32767)
```

Comment: First things first, get rid of `On Error Resume Next`.  It's evil, and probably hiding the root cause of your issues

Comment: Why would you `Sleep` a random time lapse? Perhaps you need a minimum `Sleep` time.

Comment: "(...)VBA webscraping would do this in serial(...)" - did you check this out: http://www.analystcave.com/excel-vba-multithreading-tool/ ?

Comment: Your problem is probably the last two rows - some threads are trying to write to the Workbook while it is locked by another thread for writing. You may need to do a check if the write was successful and if not Sleep and retry.

Comment: If this is internal: can't you read the information directly from the database instead of scraping it from a website?

Answer (score 2):

1. To emphasize chris' point: Test your task with the EVIL global OERN removed/disabled. As the OERN **hides** errors and lets your script **continue in an undefined state**, there should be a law "don't ask questions based on an active global OERN here".
2. Use the taskmanager to monitor your task: Any Excel zombies? Memory exhaustion?
3. The .Status of the WinHttpRequest should be checked.
4. The results of both InStr() calls should be checked - especially if you use them in a substraction (y - x) in a Mid() call.
5. The timeout after the Mid() call makes no sense (Mid() won't return before the substring is ready); doing a random wait for a resource is a bad idea in general [(c) sancho].
6. Post **all** relevant code: Surely the are calls to .Save, .Close and .Quit? Do you really write everything to the same workbook, sheet, cell [(c)  AnalystCave]?
7. Consider: Isn't starting 600 simultaneous requests on your server a DOS attack?